# como colocar a classe lembrete em uma lista;

Tags: c#, lista

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que vai ser como uma agenda e nele vai ter uma parte para guardar lembretes, o que eu queria saber é como colocar a classe lembrete em uma fila( aparecer na fila vários lembretes diferentes).

CÓDIGO

CLASSE DO LEMBRETE:

```
class Lembrete
    {
        private String anotar;
        private String data;


        public Lembrete(String anotarx, String datax)
        {
            anotar = anotarx;
            data = datax;
        }

        public String Anotar
        {
            get
            {

                return anotar;
            }
            set
            {

                anotar = value;

            }
        }

        public String Data
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                data = value;

            }
        }
        public String RetornarLembrete()
        {

            String texto = "";

            texto = anotar + "" + data  ;
            return texto;

##### PROGAM.CS ####


              //Declaração de variaveis utilizadas
            string titulo;
            int opcao1 = 1;
            int opcao2 = 2;
            int opcao3 = 3;
            int opcao = 0;
            string anotação;
            int quantidade_de_lembretes;
            //Instanciando as classes
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario("Marques", "vencedor123", "Isaac Dias");
            Importancia importancia = new Importancia("Muito importante", "Importante", "Razoavel");
            Lembrete Entradalembrete = new Lembrete(" ", " ");
            Diario Diario = new Diario("Diario");



            //Efeituando o login do usuario
            Console.WriteLine("Oi meu chapa, faça seu login");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Digite seu nick");
            usuario.Login = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Digite sua senha");
            usuario.Senha = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();



                //Se o usuario logar
            if (usuario.Login == "Marques" && usuario.Senha == "vencedor123")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Voce desejar usar o Lembrete ou o Diario, Diario 1, Lembrete 2");
                int escolha = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (escolha == 2)
                {
                    //Declarando a numeração de importância
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite: 1 ou 2 ou 3 " + "\n 1 se sua anotação for muito importante " + " \n 2 se sua anotação for importante" + " \n 3 se sua anotação e razoavel");
                    opcao = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine(" Digite o titulo da anotação");
                    titulo = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();

                    Console.WriteLine("Bem vindo ao: " + titulo);
                    //Importancia das anotações
                    if (opcao == opcao1 || opcao == opcao2 || opcao == opcao3)
                    {

                        if (opcao == opcao1)
                        {


                            Console.WriteLine("O que você tem de muito importante para anotar?");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            importancia.MuitoImportante = Console.ReadLine();
                            Entradalembrete.Anotar = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Pra quando");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            importancia.MuitoImportante = Console.ReadLine();
                            Entradalembrete.Data = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Clear();
                        }
                        else if (opcao == opcao2)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("O que você tem de importante para anotar?");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            importancia.Importante = Console.ReadLine();
                            Entradalembrete.Anotar = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            importancia.Importante = Console.ReadLine();
                            Entradalembrete.Data = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Pra quando");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                            importancia.Importante = Console.ReadLine();
                            Entradalembrete.Data = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Clear();
                        }
                        else if (opcao == opcao3)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("O que você tem de razoavel para anotar?");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                            importancia.Razoavel = Console.ReadLine();
                            Entradalembrete.Anotar = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                            importancia.Razoavel = Console.ReadLine();
                            Entradalembrete.Data = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Pra quando");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                            importancia.Razoavel = Console.ReadLine();
                            Entradalembrete.Data = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    //Notificação do lembrete
                    Console.WriteLine("Você tem um novo lembrete, deseja vê-lo? Se sim digite 1 se não digite 2");
                    int resultado = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (resultado == 1)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(Entradalembrete.Anotar + "   " + Entradalembrete.Data);

                    }
                    else if (resultado == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Deseja anotar mais algo? Se sim digite 1 se não digite 2");
                        int anotar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (anotar == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(titulo);
                            anotação = Console.ReadLine();

                        }
                        else if (anotar == 2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Obrigado pela escolha!");
                            Console.ReadKey(true);

                        }
                    }
                        //Se o usuario escolher o Diario
                    else if (escolha == 1)
                    {



                        Console.WriteLine("Digite a senha para usar o diario. ");


                        Diario.Senhad = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (Diario.Senhad != "Diario")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ops,voce digitou sua senha errada");
                        }
                        if (Diario.Senhad == "Diario")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Bem vindo");
                            Console.WriteLine("Digite algo do Dia:");
                            int resultadod = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Você deseja salvar. Se sim digite 1 Se nao digite 2");
                        int salvar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (salvar == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Salvo");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Pronto");
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            //Se o usuario não logar
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usuário não encontrado!");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            string[] listaslembretesArray = new string[5];
            listaslembretesArray[0] = importancia.MuitoImportante;
            listaslembretesArray[1] = importancia.MuitoImportante;
            listaslembretesArray[2] = importancia.MuitoImportante;
            listaslembretesArray[3] = importancia.MuitoImportante;
            listaslembretesArray[4] = importancia.MuitoImportante;




            Console.ReadKey(true);
            //Até aqui por enquanto...
```

Comment: Fila: `Queue<Lembrete> lembretes = new Queue<Lembrete>();` / Lista: `List<Lembrete> lembretes = new List<Lembrete>();` ????

Comment: Ana, edite a sua pergunta com seu código se possível.

Comment: ok. editado :p ^^

Comment: @Analuiza você precisa disso: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx